# Me sale el error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2" en el navegador al darle inspeccionar, lo que hago es abrir un carrito

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
   fetch('http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
   .then(response => {
      return response.json();
})

.then(data =>{         **//Aqui es donde me marca el error**
    console.log(data);
    let tablaCont = document.querySelector('#tabla');
    let precioTotal = '';
    let html = ``;
    data.items.forEach(element => {
        html += `
            <div class='fila'>
                <div class='imagen'><img src='img/${element.imagen}' width='100' /></div>
                <div class='info'>
                    <input type='hidden' value='${element.id}' />
                    <div class='nombre'>${element.nombre}</div>
                    <div>${element.cantidad} items de $${element.precio}</div>
                    <div>Subtotal: $${element.subtotal}</div>
                    <div class='botones'><button class='btn-remove'>Quitar 1 del carrito</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    });
```

**>Este es es el codigo del creador donde me base** https://github.com/marcosrivasr/Curso-PHP-MySQL/blob/master/58-60.%20carrito/terminado/js/main.js[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les muestro que le doy click al carrito y aparece el error.

Comment: Si no me di a entender, con gusto aclaro

Answer (score 0):

Cuando aparece "`<`" quiere decir que está recibiendo html en lugar de json. 
`<!doctype>` etc...
"`<`" es el primer carácter que lee y por ello se detiene al momento.

Answer (score 0):

Esto que tienes aqui:

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
   fetch('http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
   .then(response => {
      return response.json();
});
```

**NO** te esta devolviendo un `JSON`, te esta devolviendo un error o algo que no es un json desde el archivo en que devuelves la respuesta, puedes comprobar que cosa te esta devolviendo el servidor colocando un `console.log` de la response antes de intentar parsear el `JSON`, que por cierto te falta cerrar una llave en el `then`:

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
   fetch('http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
   }
});
```

Lo mas probable es que te este devolviendo un error la respuesta, y pues... no hace falta decir que un error no se puede parsear a un JSON...

Esto lo se porque por ejemplo si usas `PHP` para devolver algún `JSON`, hacia el frontend, si existen errores en `PHP` el valor devuelto no seria tu `JSON`, si no que se parecería a algo como esto:

```
<br> warning!, undefined variable msg in 82:10
<br>
```

O algo mas o menos de ese estilo, como podemos ver eso no es un `JSON` valido.

**¿Solución a ello?**

Aparentemente enviás datos por `GET` según veo en la `URL`:

```
'http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar'
```

Así que como enviás datos por `GET` puedes ir directamente a esa `URL` a ver que esta pasando y una vez encuentres el error y lo soluciones, tu `fetch` debería funcionar con éxito.

Bueno, exceptuando un problema de lógica que tienes... y es que debes retornar la respuesta de `fetch`, la cual es una `promesa` y luego usarla donde desees, en tu caso tu tienes esto:

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
   fetch('http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
   .then(response => {
      return response.json();
})
```

Y deberías tener esto:

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
   return fetch('http://localhost/Wavystore/Api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
   }
});
```

Y donde lo vayas a usar deberás usarlo de esta manera:

```
actualizarCarrito().then(response =>{

   /*
     response es tu json, solo podras obtener la informacion 
     dentro de .then puesto que actualizarCarrito retorna una promise.
     (aviso de antemano que nisiquiera intentes sacar el valor
     de fetch directamente para no tener que usar then o catch
     porque a menos que uses await no vas a poder).
   */ 
   console.log(response);

}).catch(e => console.error(e.message));
```

Una ultima cosa, tienes errores en esta parte:

```
    html += `
        <div class='fila'>
            <div class='imagen'><img src='img/${element.imagen}' width='100' /></div>
            <div class='info'>
                <input type='hidden' value='${element.id}' />
                <div class='nombre'>${element.nombre}</div>
                <div>${element.cantidad} items de $${element.precio}</div>
                <div>Subtotal: $${element.subtotal}</div>
                <div class='botones'><button class='btn-remove'>Quitar 1 del carrito</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
```

Los errores son muy sencillos y se encuentran a simple vista, por lo que solo te dire que existen errores en ese template, debes buscarlos y erradicarlos.